# How do I stop a jquery click function on several divs after one div is clicked?

Tags: jquery, ajax, scope, onclick

I have several divs with a click function that essentially "votes" for your chosen box.

This works great until someone wants to choose a second or third box as well.  The click function is tied to the class of the divs so I somehow need to disable the click function after it's clicked once.

```
$('.vote').on('click',function(){
    $(this).append('<div id="voted">Thanks!<form><input type="text" name="comment"></form></div>');
});

<div class="vote">Option A</div>
<div class="vote">Option B</div>
<div class="vote">Option C</div>
```

I have to use the "one" function to disable the click function on the current div so that a user can click the form input.  The problem is that the other options are still "clickable".  So a user can vote for all three options if they like.  How can I limit this to one vote?

Comment: Quick point - in your HTML, classes don't need a period. It's just class="vote"

Comment: Sorry, quickly typing an example.  You're right and my code does not have this.  Question updated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

classes should not start with a period :

```
<div class="vote">Option A</div>
<div class="vote">Option B</div>
<div class="vote">Option C</div>
```

Use a flag to make the entire class clickable only once :

```
var flag = true;

$('.vote').one('click',function(){
    if (flag) {
        $(this).append('<div id="vote">Thanks!<form><input type="text" name="comment"></form></div>');
        flag = false;
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mbeyQ/)

Comment: And I assume add a flag = false; in the if flag?

Answer (score 3):

While both offered solutions will work, it make sense to remove event handler as it is not going to be used anyway.

I would sugest this code

```
 $('.vote').on('click.vote', function () {
      $(this).append('<div id="voted">Thanks!<form><input type="text" name="comment"></form></div>');
      $('.vote').off('click.vote');
 });
```

Using namespaced events you will not alter other click event handlers if there are ones.

Comment: crap, was just typing this! This is a much better idea IMO. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
var clicked=0;

$('.vote').on('click',function(){
    if(clicked==0){
        clicked=1;
            $(this).append('<div id="voted">Thanks!<form><input type="text" name="comment"></form></div>');
    }
});
```

Use a variable. Set its value